# Unexpected TypeError in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, if-statement, typeerror

Goal: Write a function which determines if an array of objects contains an object with a given value for a given field. Return the object if there is such an object and return false otherwise.

**The code**

```
var data = [
    {isle: 'VF', item: 'Ginger'},
    {isle: 'VF', item: 'Spinach'},
    {isle: 'Dairy', item: 'Milk'},
    {isle: 'Dairy', item: 'Yogurt'}
];

var objwithPropvalueInarr = function(propname, propvalue, arr){
    for(var i=0; i <= arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i][propname] === propvalue) {
            // console.log('Found object with value ' + propvalue);
            return arr[i];
        }
    };
    return false;
};
```

I entered the above code in Google Chrome console. The following call to the function works:

```
objwithPropvalueInarr('isle', 'VF', data)
```

The line above returns `data[0]` as expected.

However, the following call returns an TypeError (shown after the call)

```
objwithPropvalueInarr('isle', 'nonexistentpropvalue', data)

TypeError: Cannot read property 'isle' of undefined
arguments: Array[2]
get message: function () { [native code] }
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set message: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
type: "non_object_property_load"
__proto__: Error
```

`data[0]['isle'] === 'nonexistentpropvalue'` returns `false` as expected. Should the `if` condition in the function not return `false` for every check and then return the `false` value at the end. Would appreciate if someone can explain the error.

Thank you.

Comment: Also, using Developer Tools you can discover such problems much faster than asking them on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
```

Using `<=` will go outside the bounds of the array.

***[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9mw3x/)***

Comment: Thanks. Now, of course, is works. Have to wait 8 minutes to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is becaouse you should change code to `for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){`: since array length = arr.length, last element index is arr.length - 1, so you just got arr[arr.length] as null object.

Comment: The index of the last element is `arr.length - 1`.